# How to override a function of extjs in CQ/AEM?

Tags: extjs, aem

I'm using selection Xtype and checkbox type property (CQ.form.Selection) to create a checkbox group in CQ5 (API docs at http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection). 
But I want to override setValue, getValue and validate functions of it in order to meet my requirement. How can I do that via JCR node declaration ?

many thanks and appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "do that via JCR node declaration". But if you need to make a few additional steps with standard xtype you just need to create a custom xtype, which wraps the standard one, and use it.
Here is an [example](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-xtype.html#main-pars_text_26) of JS-code that creates and registers new xtype (combines values of 2 different fields into a single value).

```
Ejst.CustomWidget = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

/**
 * @private
 * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
 */
hiddenField: null,

/**
 * @private
 * @type CQ.Ext.form.ComboBox
 */
allowField: null,

/**
 * @private
 * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
 */
otherField: null,

constructor: function(config) {
    config = config || { };
    var defaults = {
        "border": false,
        "layout": "table",
        "columns":2
    };
    config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
    Ejst.CustomWidget.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
},

// overriding CQ.Ext.Component#initComponent
initComponent: function() {
    Ejst.CustomWidget.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

    this.hiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
        name: this.name
    });
    this.add(this.hiddenField);

    this.allowField = new CQ.form.Selection({
        type:"select",
        cls:"ejst-customwidget-1",
        listeners: {
            selectionchanged: {
                scope:this,
                fn: this.updateHidden
            }
        },
        optionsProvider: this.optionsProvider
    });
    this.add(this.allowField);

    this.otherField = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
        cls:"ejst-customwidget-2",
        listeners: {
            change: {
                scope:this,
                fn:this.updateHidden
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.otherField);

},

// overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#processPath
processPath: function(path) {
    console.log("CustomWidget#processPath", path);
    this.allowField.processPath(path);
},

// overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#processRecord
processRecord: function(record, path) {
    console.log("CustomWidget#processRecord", path, record);
    this.allowField.processRecord(record, path);
},

// overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#setValue
setValue: function(value) {
    var parts = value.split("/");
    this.allowField.setValue(parts[0]);
    this.otherField.setValue(parts[1]);
    this.hiddenField.setValue(value);
},

// overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getValue
getValue: function() {
    return this.getRawValue();
},

// overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getRawValue
getRawValue: function() {
    if (!this.allowField) {
        return null;
    }
    return this.allowField.getValue() + "/" +
           this.otherField.getValue();
},

// private
updateHidden: function() {
    this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
}

});

// register xtype
CQ.Ext.reg('ejstcustom', Ejst.CustomWidget);
```

[Creating custom xtype in AEM6's touch UI](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-xtypes.html)

Comment: "superclass" is the key mojo for making this work for me. Thanks